# Howto pass array in ajax call to controller and return it with Symfony3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

Hi and thanks for helping me, I have a ajax call with data I would like to send to the Controller so I can delete the specified data at a later time. For the moment I would like to show the given javascript from the controller. Sorry in advance for my English, it's not my first language.

It's currently returning a JsonResponse to test if the method is called but I want to return the given javascript array (playlogs) instead, how can I do that?

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#deleteBtn').click(function () {
               var playlogs = [];

               $.each($("input[name='playlog']:checked"), function () {
                   playlogs.push($(this).val());
               });
               var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this?";
               if (confirm(confirmText)) {
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "delete",
                       url: '{{ path('playlog_delete_bulk') }}',
                       data: playlogs,
                       success: function () {
                           alert("selected playlogs: " + playlogs.join(", "));
                       },
                   });
               }
               return false;
           });

       });
   </script>
```

**deleteBulkAction in PlayLogController:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/bulk", name="playlog_delete_bulk")
 */
public function deleteBulkAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => 'Successfully called the named route playlog_delete_bulk  '));
    }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send playlogs as json (or any other format, depends on data). Read request body by `$request->getContent()` and decode it in php array.

Ex.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#deleteBtn').click(function () {
           var playlogs = [];
           $.each($("input[name='playlog']:checked"), function () {
               playlogs.push($(this).val());
           });

           var confirmText = "Are you sure you want to delete this?";

           if (confirm(confirmText)) {
               $.ajax({
                   type: "delete",
                   url: '{{ path('playlog_delete_bulk') }}',
                   data: JSON.stringify(playlogs),
                   success: function (data) {
                      alert("selected playlogs: " + data.join(", "));
                   }
               });
           }
           return false;
       });

   });
```

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/bulk", name="playlog_delete_bulk")
 */
public function deleteBulkAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        return new JsonResponse(json_decode($request->getContent()));
    }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

Comment: How do I decode it in a php array something like this:             $array =  JsonResponse(json_decode($request->getContent()));
            return $array;

Comment: I now get this error: "The controller must return a response (Array(0 => 25, 1 => 11, 2 => 24, 3 => 14, 4 => 17, 5 => 26) given, with:             $array = json_decode($request->getContent());
            var_dump($array);
            return $array;

Comment: controller should return `Response`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html

Answer (score 0):

Use 'request' ParameterBag to access POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE data

```
  $password = $request->request->get('password');
```

and 'query' - for GET data

```
  $pageNumber = $request->query->get('page');
```

Comment: Ths is not working for me, I get a error 400.
            $array =  $request->request->get('playlogs');
            var_dump($array);

Comment: 400 error has nothing to do with this.
get() will either return parameter or NULL. What do you get with $request->getContent()?

Comment: I've set the type to POST and now it's working, but how do I use this "new response" in a php array? This throws me a bad request:             $array =  new Response($request->request->get('playlogs'));
            var_dump($array);

Comment: Oh my. Don't create new Response, use the one that Symfony sends into your action.